# Horizontally scrolling set of images scrolls jerkily upon launch but then smooths out

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, sencha-touch, extjs

I've got a sencha touch app, with a panel that contains 3 image buttons, and the idea is that you can use flick scrolling to scroll them left or right to press the correct one.

The first time (after each load of the app) that you touch or flick these buttons, it doesn't scroll, or it scrolls jerkily. It works ok if you touch it and hold your finger steady for half a second before moving. After that initial time it flicks nicely.

The panel is constructed like so:

```
var picScroller = { // The picture scroller
  flex: 1,
  cls: 'items',
  scroll: 'horizontal',
  layout: 'hbox',
  defaults: {
    width: 235,
    height: 160
  },
  items: [
    { width: 32 },
    { xtype: 'button', id:"bn1", cls:'myimagebutton', pressedCls:'', handler: myHandler },
    { xtype: 'button', id:"bn2", cls:'myimagebutton', pressedCls:'', handler: myHandler },
    { xtype: 'button', id:"bn3", cls:'myimagebutton', pressedCls:'', handler: myHandler },
    { width: 32 }
  ]
};
```

And my CSS is like so:

```
.myimagebutton {
  border:0;
  border-radius:0;
  margin:10px;
}
```

Any suggestions? thanks so much

Comment: I guess its taking some time to load the items... some programmed delay or pre-fetching might help ?

Comment: Do you mean to load the images? I removed the third image from the JS so it is now only two, and they are both fully loaded because i can see the left-hand side of the second image before i start flicking, but it still jerks, so i don't think that's the problem.

Comment: I've tried with the iScroll script instead of sencha, and it's all smooth, doesn't display this problem. So this problem seems to be with sencha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an article that lists a solution to a similar-sounding problem (although this may be specific to being used in conjunction with PhoneGap): http://www.senchatouchbits.com/6/fixing-flickering-of-animations-in-phonegap.html

Comment: Well, for the record we gave up on sencha for performance issues, especially on android, and went native. Obj-c FTW!